# NGINX Openresty - access log format - align the output

Tags: nginx, openresty

i'm using NGINX Openresty (version 1.4.3.4) in my project and i was wondering if i could make the access log to be aligned.

from this:

```
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.028] [200] [54.162.222.95] ["GET /XXX"]
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.020] [200] [108.177.223.182] ["GET /XXX"]
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.022] [204] [208.43.79.196] ["POST /XXX"]
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.018] [204] [173.192.139.113]  ["GET /XXX"]
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.019] [200] [54.152.215.46]  ["GET /XXX"]
```

to look like this

```
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.028] [200] [54.162.222.95]   ["GET /XXX"]
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.020] [200] [108.177.223.182] ["GET /XXX"]
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.022] [204] [208.43.79.196]   ["POST /XXX"]
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.018] [204] [173.192.139.113] ["GET /XXX"]
[06/Mar/2015:21:20:11 +0000] [0.019] [200] [54.152.215.46]   ["GET /XXX"]
```

what i have currently in my settings is this:

```
log_format normal '[$time_local] [$request_time] [$status] [$http_x_forwarded_for] ["$request"]';
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't align log with `log_format` to what you want.

You can make your own log with [log_by_lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#log_by_lua) to any format you want.